# Would it be worthy to broadcast small variables in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast

According to [Spark Tuning Tips](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#broadcasting-large-variables), broadcast functionality can be used on large objects to reduce the size of each serialized task.

This makes sense to me, but my question would be, for small objects like Integer or Boolean objects, would it still be worthy to have object creation overhead to broadcast them? My hunch is that it is discouraged, but I couldn't find any convincing explanation on this top online, please help out if you have done some benchmarking and study.

Here is the code to define the variables:

```
final Broadcast<String> someFolderBroadcast = javaSparkContext.broadcast(someFolder);
final Broadcast<Boolean> someModeBroadcast = javaSparkContext.broadcast(isSomeMode);
```

someFolderBroadcast.value() and someModeBroadcast.value() are used to retrieve the stored values in the Broadcast variables.

Comment: Spark prints the serialized size of each task on the master, so you can look at that to decide whether your tasks are too large.In general, tasks larger than about 20 KB are probably worth optimizing. So what is the size of your tasks?

Comment: @eliasah, I couldn't run the program on cluster because I am doing a code review. The original author was broadcasting single boolean or integer variables, which I believe is not worthy the overhead of creating a Broadcast object, but I couldn't find any article on related topics..

Comment: post the code you are executing

Comment: @eliasah, I have edited the question and please take a look and let me know what do you think, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are these variables larger than 20kb?

Comment: If not, don't broadcast them!

Answer (score 2):

Spark prints the serialized size of each task on the master, so you can look at that to decide whether your tasks are too large.In general, tasks larger than about 20 KB are probably worth optimizing.

So if your variables (or tasks) are larger than 20 KB, broadcast them!